# Does the cancellation of my wife's US visa at the point of entry affect mine?

Tags: visas, usa, nigerian-citizens, visa-cancellation

Does the cancellation of my wife's US visa at the point of entry (for not telling the embassy she was pregnant) affect mine as the principal applicant, if we travel separately?

Comment: Although am yet to travel with my visa

Comment: You are unlikely to be delivered of an anchor baby.

Answer (score 1):

Your visas were issued independently so the answer is NO. The cancellation of you wife's does not affect you. Unless the issuance of the visa was predicated upon the same information that you both provided.